# How to use Ivy/Ant to build using intermediate artifacts

Tags: ivy

I am trying to revise my build process to use ant with apache ivy for my personal projects. These consist of a few shared modules, and a few application modules that depend on the shared modules. For the sake of this post, let's simplify and say I have a shared module (`common`), and an application module (`application`) which depends on `common`. Each module has it's own effective svn repository:

```
svn_repo_1/common/trunk
                 /branches
                 /tags
svn_repo_2/application/trunk
                      /branches
                      /tags
```

I check out the relevant revision into a common workspace, in a flat structure:

```
workspace/common
workspace/application
```

In general, `application` will depend on a published version of `common`, so there will be no need to build `common` when building `application`.

However, when I need to add new functionality to `common` that is required by `application`, I would then like `application` to depend on the latest `common` build from my workspace (without needing to publish common to my repository).

I assumed this is what `latest.integration` meant (i.e. changing `application`'s ivy.xml to specify latest.integration for the common revision). My intention was to use the ivy `buildlist` task to find the local modules that needed to be built before application could be built. This does not work however, because the `buildlist` task seems to include the common/build.xml entry regardless of whether application's ivy.xml file specifies latest.integration or some other published revision.

I would appreciate any suggestions. I am struggling with ivy's documentation and samples, so any real-world examples would also be helpful. Note: I am not interested in a Maven solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is truly deja vu! Go back to some of my first questions on this site from 3 - 4 months ago and they're almost all Ivy-related! I empathize with you 100% that Ivy is a difficult beast to learn and tame, but after using it professionally for a few months now, I'll never develop without it again. So my first piece of advice: *keep going*. Sooner or later, what little (practical) documentation you find on Apache Ivy will alll start to make sense and fall into play.

I can understand there may be extenuating reasons for why you don't want to publish your `common` to your repo. However, if you are a newcome to transitive dependency management, the first piece of practical advice I can give you is that you should *always* publish your JARs/WARs/whatever to your repo; not an intermediary "integration" local to your workspace.

The reason for this is simple: Ivy only has the ability to crawl the repositories you define in your settings file (basically). If you deliberately keep a JAR like `common` outside of one of these defined repositories, then: (a) Ivy has no way to resolve transitive dependencies (its primary job), and (b) "downstream" (dependent) JARs fail to be dynamically updated every time you tweak `common`. Thus, using Ivy only to *not* publish JARs is a bit counter-productive; I'm surprised Ivy even includes it as a feature.

I guess I would need to understand your motivation for not publishing `common`. If you're simply having problems getting the `ivy:publish` task to work, no worries I can provide plenty of examples to help get you started. But if there are some other reasons, then I ask you to consider this solution: **set up multiple repositories**.

Perhaps you have one "primary" repository where mostly everything gets published; and then you have a "secondary" or "intermediary" repository where you publish `common` to whenever it makes sense (for you) to do that. You can then configure your Ant build with two different publish tasks, such as **publish-main** and **publish-integration**.

That way you get the best of both worlds: you get your intermediary staging area, and you get to keep everything inside of Ivy's powerful control.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My reason for not wanting `common` published while building intermediate builds is because I'm using ivysvn for my main repository - so published artifacts are checked in to a separate svn repository. I don't want a common-latest.integration.jar being continually committed. I like the sound of your multiple repositories suggestion. Would I be able to resolve using both repositories, so that the 3rd party artifacts in my main ivysvn repository are resolved from there, while my common-latest.integration.jar is resolved from a local directory repository?